# How to make a mysql table with date and time columns?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am trying to create a table that has date and time columns used to store the date and time information when the entry is recorded in the database. In the MySQL documentation shows the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The problem is that I want separate fields for date and time. On another site I found this piece of code that suits my needs for the date:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, date_added DATE);
```

but I wasn't able to find anything like that for the time.
Will the following piece of code make separate date and time fields that would be filled as the entry is recorded?

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, date_added DATE, time_added TIME);
```

Comment: what is the difference? Splitting them into two fields would be the same as keeping them in the same field. The important thing is that you have the data available.

Comment: no, with that last code snippet you now need to rely on your application to do that for you.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos do I need both timestamp and datetime, seems like they do the same thing.

Comment: That is my point. Both date AND time can be found in the TIMESTAMP: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no point in having separate columns for Date and Time. It does not make much sense

You can create the table like this

```
CREATE TABLE timeDate (
   id INT,
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
);
```

And if you want the Date part use this query

```
SELECT DATE(`ts`) FROM timedate WHERE id =someId
```

And if you want the Time part use this query

```
SELECT TIME(`ts`) FROM timedate WHERE id =someId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIME,
  dt DATE
);
```

Only a timestamp field can have DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. It contains both a date and time. TIME and DATE fields will need to be set by your application.