# Can I add rows to MySQL before removing all old rows (except same primary)?

Tags: mysql

If I have a table that has these rows:

```
animal (primary)
-------
man
dog
cow
```

and I want to delete all the rows and insert my new rows (that may contain some of the same data), such as:

```
animal (primary)
-------
dog
chicken
wolf
```

I could simply do something like:

```
delete from animal;
```

and then insert the new rows.

But when I do that, for a split second, 'dog' won't be accessible through the SELECT statement.

I could simply insert ignore the new data and then delete the rest, one by one, but that doesn't feel like the right solution when I have a lot of rows.

Is there a way to insert the new data and then have MySQL automatically delete the rest afterward?

I have a program that selects data from this table every 5 minutes (and the code I'm writing now will be updating this table once every 30 minutes), so I would like to be as accurate as possible at all times, and I would rather have too many rows for a split second than too few rows for the same time.

Note: I know that this may seem like it is unnecessary but I just feel like if I leave too many of those unlikely possibilities in different places, there will be times where things go wrong.

Comment: If your data is that simple, you could delete first before inserting, as you mention. However, delete only the rows that won't be updated: `delete from the_table where animal not in ('dog','otheranimals to be inserted or updated')`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another column `timestamp` and change the select statement to accommodate this scenario where it needs to check for the latest value. 
If this is for school, I would argue that **you need a timestamp** and that is what your professor is looking for. You shouldn't need to truncate a table to get the latest values, you need to adjust the thinking behind the table and how you are querying data. Hope this helps!

**Check out these:**

[How to make a mysql table with date and time columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572871/how-to-make-a-mysql-table-with-date-and-time-columns)

[Why not update values instead?](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

My other questions would be:

- How are you loading this into the table?
- What does that code look like?
- Can you change the way you `Select` from the table?
- What values are being "updated" and change in such a way that you need to truncate the entire table?

Comment: How would that delete the rows that are not to be updated but removed?

Comment: I just get new data and basically need to replace the whole table. I don't know if I need to update or insert new data. There are only two columns: what I call "animal" here and then "record_created", which updates automatically (and I don't really need it). So INSERT IGNORE works fine. It's just that deleting the old data is troubling me.

Comment: Check my latest answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use TRUNCATE instead of DELETE here.  TRUNCATE is faster than DELETE and resets the table back to its empty state (meaning IDENTITY columns are reset to original values as well).

Not sure why you're having problems with selecting a value that was deleted and re-added, maybe I'm missing some context.  But if you're wiping the table clean, you might want to use truncate instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add new column, there is an other method.
1. At first step, update table in any way that mark all existing rows for deletion in future. For example:

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `animal`=CONCAT('MUST_BE_DELETED_', `animal`)
```

2. At second step, insert new rows.
3. On final step, remove all marked rows:

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `animal` LIKE 'MUST_BE_DELETED_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this by having the `updated_on` column as timestamp and you may even utilize some default values, but let's go with an example without them.

I presume the table would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `animal` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (`animal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

This is just a dummy table example. What's important are the two queries later on.

You would simply perform a query to insert the data, such as:

```
insert into my_table(animal)
select animal from my_view where animal = 'dogs'
on duplicate key update
updated_on = current_timestamp;
```

Please notice that my_view is your table/view/query by which you supply the values to insert into your table. Also notice that you need to have primary/unique key constraint on your `animal` column in this example, in order to work.

Then, you proceed with the following query, to "purge" (delete) the old values:

```
delete from my_table
where updated_on < (
    select * 
    from (
        select max(updated_on) from  my_table
    ) as max_date
);
```

Please notice that you could make a separate view in order to obtain this max_date value for updated_on entry. This entry should indicate the timestamp for your last updated/inserted values in a previous query, so you could proceed with utilizing it in a `where` clause in order to issue deletion of old records that you don't want/need anymore.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
Since you are doing multiple queries and it's supposed to be a single operation, I'd advise you to utilize it within a single trancations and to utilize a proper rollback on various potential outcomes (i.e. in case of mysql exceptions). You might wish to utilize a proper stored procedure for that.